# ruby complains about a package being not installed which actually is installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora-21

This question might be very unprofessional but I'm very not into Ruby and I have no clue where to start..

I used to run `Jekyll` which runs `asciidoctor` to render html pages.

After a Fedora update unfortunately I just get the message

```
$ jekyll serve
...
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::AsciiDocConverter encountered an error while converting '<some file>':
                  asciidoctor: FAILED: required gem 'pygments.rb' is not installed. Processing aborted.
```

I tried to install `pygments.rb` (as current user and/or as root) this way:

```
gem install pygments.rb
```

But it's already installed. When I remove it (in order to reinstall it) I get a hint:

```
$ gem uninstall pygments.rb

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    pygments.rb-0.6.3
```

When I then try to run Jekyll/asciidoctor the message looks different:

```
$ jekyll serve
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'pygments.rb' (~> 0.6.0) among 72 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:1295:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:1284:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb:1266:in `activate'
    from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:54:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

So in this case `Jekyll` seems to miss `pygments.rb` while in the other case (when `pygments.rb` is installed) it looks like `asciidoctor` is complaining.

Can you give me a hint where I should start to investigate?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall `Jekyll` as well?

Comment: I did now. With no effect I'm afraid. I'm still getting `asciidoctor: FAILED: required gem 'pygments.rb' is not installed. Processing aborted.`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It's Fedora 21 server edition. `ruby 2.1.5p273` with `jekyll-2.5.3` `pygments.rb-0.6.3` and `jekyll-asciidoc-1.0.0` installed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `python-pygments` package installed, e.g.

```
yum install python-pygments
```

The gem is only a wrapper for it.

Comment: `python-pygments` is installed and up to date (I even tried `python3-pygments`)